# What are a cyclic $k$-algebra and a monoid $k$-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, definition

I am trying assignments of algebraic geometry from an online course and these definitions were not mentioned in theory.

So, can you please help me with understanding them?

> 1. Let $k$ be a field. Let $B= k[x]$ be a cyclic $k$-algebra.

What does it mean for a $k$-algebra to be cyclic? A $k$-algebra is a pair of a ring and ring homomorphism.

> 2. Let $ B = k [ {\mathbb{N}}^2]$ be the monoid algebra over $k$ of the additive monoid $\mathbb{N}^2$.

So, can you please help me with these definitions?

Comment: I would add that calling such an algebra "cyclic" is really not that common, and in my opinion it is a horribly bad terminology.

Comment: @Avenger Regardless of who or what the source of this *cyclic algebra* terminology might be, forget you even heard of it and replace it instead with the only proper manner of expressing the intended meaning, which is *monogenous* algebra. This term also has the advantage of being self-explanatory: one is referring to algebras generated by a single (mono) element. By the way, the definition you mention in general for algebras as being *a pair of a ring and ring morphism* is not actually generally valid, *(to be cont.)*

Comment: @Avenger *(cont.)* but it merely represents a *characterisation* for a particular class of algebras, namely those that are *associative* and *unital*. In general, $E$ is an algebra over given *commutative* ring $A$ if it is a module over $A$ further equipped with a binary internal operation - the multiplication of the algebra structure - subject to no other axiom than that of being $A$-bilinear. In general the multiplication is not even required to be associative, and this is precisely the case with *Lie* algebras: they are not associative yet they are nevertheless genuine algebras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Cyclic means single generator. In this case, that generator is $x$. (It is *very* common to take the homomorphism $k\to k[x]$ to be the "standard" one taking $1\mapsto 1$ and extending $k$-linearly and not discuss this at all, if you're worried about that part of things.)
2. It's just like a group algebra, but with monoids instead. In particular, given a ring $R$ and a monoid $\mathcal{M}$, the monoid algebra $R[\mathcal{M}]$ is the free $R$-module on the elements of $\mathcal{M}$ with multiplication defined by applying the monoid operation: that is, if $a,b\in\mathcal{M}$ with associated basis elements $e_a$ and $e_b$ respectively, then $e_a\cdot e_b=e_{a\cdot b}$. You can check that in your specific case, $k[\Bbb N^2]\cong k[x,y]$ with $x$ corresponding to $(1,0)$ and $y$ corresponding to $(0,1)$.

Comment: "It's just like a group algebra"   What is a group algebra?  Did you meant ring algebra because in my definition I mentioned only rings no groups?

Comment: See [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupAlgebra.html) for instance. A group algebra is the same construction but with a group instead of a monoid: it's a free module on the elements of the group where multiplication is defined by sending $e_a\cdot e_b$ to $e_{a\cdot b}$. I mentioned it because it's a more commonly used construction (at least where I am) - often it's introduced in abstract algebra courses dealing with representations, which is something you might have seen before your current course.

Comment: but K algebra is very different than group algebra.

Comment: If you choose the base ring to be $k$, then your group algebra or monoid algebra is an instance of a $k$-algebra. I don't really understand why the mere mention in that one sentence is so troubling to you?

Comment: so does that means that there exists a p such that It will generate B ie there always exists $k \in K$ such that k p=b? Is that right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly you're asking about in that last comment. It looks like you're writing down the definition of a cyclic $k$-module, but there are plenty of cyclic $k$-algebras and monoid algebras over $k$ which are not cyclic as modules.

Comment: k[x] is a cyclic k-algebra. You said it means that there exists a single generator say p. So, how will you write any element of k[x] in terms of p?

Comment: You write it as a *polynomial* in $p$ with coefficients from $k$. Remember, in an algebra, we have multiplication as well as addition. (Also, please use MathJax in the comments - it makes it much easier to understand what you're saying.)