# Why are subalgebras of a cyclic $k$-algebra finite type over $k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field.

> Let $B=k[x]$ be a cyclic $k$-algebra. Then every $k$-subalgebra $A$ of $B$ is a finite type $k$-algebra.

Using the definition [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4327231), take $B$ to be a $k$-algebra generated by $x$.

Case 1: If a $k$-algebra is finitely generated then every subalgebra of it will be finitely generated.

Case 2: If a $k$-algebra is not finitely generated (cyclic but infinite) then $k$-subalgebra might also be infinitely generated. Example: $k$-algebra is generated by $\{1,x,x^2,...,x^n,\dots\}$ and subalgebra is generated by $\{1,x^2,x^4,...x^{2n},\dots\}$ (even powers of $x$). So, in this case it will not be finitely generated. So, what is wrong with my reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to be careful here is of the distinction between finitely generated as a module and finitely generated as an algebra. You're mixing these terms a bit in your question, and that might lead to some confusion. Case 1 should be "if $B$ is finitely generated **as a $k$-module**," while case 2 should be "if $B$ is not finitely generated **as a $k$-module**".

As you observe in case 1, the equivalence is straightforward: given a finite generating set of size $n$ of $A$ as a $k$-module, we can define a map from $k[y_1,\cdots,y_n]$ to $A$ by sending $y_i$ to the $i^{th}$ generator, and this is surjective. Your thoughts in case 2 are not quite right, though. The $k$-algebra generated by $\{x^2,x^4,x^8,\cdots\}$ is just $k[x^2]$, which is generated by $x^2$ and therefore finitely generated.

To prove the claim in case 2, consider the set $S=\{\deg b \mid b\in B\}$. This is a submonoid of $\Bbb Z_{\geq 0}$: if there are $p,p'\in B$ with $\deg p =n$ and $\deg p'=n'$, then $\deg pp'=n+n'$. Let $d=\gcd(S)$, and choose two elements $n,n'$ of $S$ so that their greatest common divisor is $d$. Then by the [Chicken McNugget theorem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Chicken_McNugget_Theorem), there is some $N>0$ so that we can use positive-integer combinations of $n$ and $n'$ to write any element of $d\Bbb Z$ bigger than $N$. What this means in terms of elements of $B$ is that from a choice of two elements $p,p'\in B$ corresponding to $n,n'\in S$,  for all elements $b\in B$ with $\deg B> N$, we may write $b$ as the sum of an element $b'$ of degree $\leq N$ and a polynomial in $p,p'$ with coefficients in $k$.  So we can take as a generating set for $B$ the elements $p$, $p'$, and the finitely many generators necessary to express all the elements of $B$ of degree $\leq N$.

Comment: 'What this means in terms of elements of B is that..." Can you please write write the expression how you can exactly write b' in terms of b?

Comment: All integers greater than N can be written in linear combination of n and n'. with coefficients in k.

Comment: I think intuition is clear to me but can you please be more rigorious for proof after the line" What this means in terms of elements of B is that"?

Comment: @Avenger Can you please help me with this question if you have some time to spare:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4331541/jacobson-radical-of-the-jacobson-radical-of-a-is-contraction-of-jacobson-radical

Comment: @Avenger There is not generally an explicit expression. The method is to find a polynomial in $p$ and $p'$ which has the same top coefficient as $b$, subtract this polynomial from $b$ to get a lower-degree element, and continue this process until the degree of the result is $N$ or less. You already have people helping you on the linked question, I suggest you engage with them. Good day.

Comment: typo in the above: "... which has the same top **degree term** as $b$...".